# How to handle mixed types when implementing comparison operators?

Tags: python, comparison

What is the most natural way to complete the following code?

```
import functools

@functools.total_ordering
class X:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = a

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, X):
            return False
        return self._a == other._a

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, X):
            return ...                    // what should go here?
        return self._a < other._a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = [2, 'foo', X(2)]
    s.sort()
    print s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose whatever feels natural to you; `False` means your instances always sort after other types, `True` and they'll be sorted before.

Alternatively, you can return `NotImplemented` (see [the `__lt__` and other comparison methods documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)) to signal the comparison is not supported:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, X):
        return NotImplemented
    return self._a < other._a
```

Quoting the documentation:

> A rich comparison method may return the singleton `NotImplemented` if it does not implement the operation for a given pair of arguments. By convention, `False` and `True` are returned for a successful comparison. However, these methods can return any value, so if the comparison operator is used in a Boolean context (e.g., in the condition of an if statement), Python will call `bool()` on the value to determine if the result is true or false.

Comment: Just returning False or True is not a good idea. Consider the case when you have another analogous class Y and do X('foo') < Y('bar') and Y('bar') > X('foo'). The results may not be consistent.

Comment: But returning NotImplemented does work. Then Python will use its own default ordering that is somewhat arbitrary but consistent.

Answer (score 3):

**My personal approach:**

An exception.

There's no natural order between different types.

**The official one:** (choose this one, there should be)

Although I don't agree with that completely, the manual clearly states how it should be done:

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types and
>   different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered
>   consistently but arbitrarily (so that sorting a heterogeneous array
>   yields a consistent result). Furthermore, some types (for example,
>   file objects) support only a degenerate notion of comparison where any
>   two objects of that type are unequal. Again, such objects are ordered
>   arbitrarily but consistently. The <, <=, > and >= operators will raise
>   a TypeError exception when any operand is a complex number.

So basically... I would raise an exception, but the most pythonic way of doing the ordering would be to comply with the manual.

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Comment: But Python does implement such an order. I can sort the list [2.3, 'foo', int].

Comment: `1 > 'a string'` is False, `1 < 'a string'` is True.

Comment: Specifically, `TypeError("can't compare {} to {}".format(type(self), type(other)))`.

Comment: It can be very practical to have an order between different types, maybe comparing class names will do?

Comment: I've edited my reply to state what the manual says. The exception is my personal view, but I do agree it can come in handy, and since there's a clear specification for that, it should be done "by the book".